# Can redhat wireless drivers work on ubuntu?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I've recently purchased the [Aukey WF-R13](https://www.aukey.com/products/ac1200-dual-band-usb-3-0-wi-fi-adapter-with-dual-high-gain-antennas/), and although it came with Linux drivers on the disk, I'm having trouble making heads of tales of the readme. It has a makefile but I can't seem to run `./configure`. Running `make` just seems to error out.

If I run `lsusb` it shows up as

> Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0e8d:7612 MediaTek Inc.

`iwconfig` does not show any wireless devices.

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably need to contact Aukey for support. The drivers don't seem to exist on their web site, and the page you link to only says that Windows and Mac are supported.

Comment: What Ubuntu version and what kernel are you running (`uname -r`)? Your device's PCI ID is one of those apparently supported by https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210/ - so that might be worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Steeldriver suggested in the comments that the driver found at [github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210](https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210) might work.

I just tried it and I can confirm it does work. My `lsusb` command gives `Bus 003 Device 024: ID 0e8d:7612 MediaTek Inc` and if yours is the same then give it a try.